# Use of :has and ::before in css

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't this work? Specifically, I'm trying to show some text in a div, if it contains a hidden form...

```css
form.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div:has(form.hidden)::before {
  color: red;
  font-size: x-large;
  content: 'This DIV has a hidden FORM';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="hidden">
    form
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:has()` is an experimental feature, no browsers support it yet . Please see the browser compatibility chart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

The spec also indicates that it cannot be used in stylesheets:

> The :has() pseudo-class takes a selector list as an argument. In the current specification :has is not marked as part of the live selector profile, which means it can not be used within stylesheets; only with functions like document.querySelector().

Comment: Ah, that would explain it :) What about with SASS?

Comment: @user4893295 SASS is only a preprocessor, it generates plain CSS  where :has() is not avalaible. SASS has nothing to do with the document content, it is not used to parse it.

Comment: Although relevant, is the problem not related to the `content` input?

Comment: @G-Cyr sure, but wondered if preprocessing might give a deeply clever way of doing it ;)